# How to find if any element of list contains a substring without using for loop

Tags: python-3.x, string

Let's say I have

`list = ["tree", "gate", "buy", "train", "test"]`

and I have string as follows:

`string = "rain"`

I want to use a rule to understand if any element of list contains my string or not. For this case I want this turns True.

I know that I can do it like that:

```
flag = False
for element in list:
    if string in element:
        flag = True
```

However, I want to know if there is a method for that. Or there is a way to control this in a simple if statement?

Thank you.

Comment: Does a generator expression or list comprehension count as a "for loop" for you?

Comment: you could write `any(string in element for element in list)` but basically its just another way of writing the same thing

Comment: If you want to avoid the `for` keyword you could use `any(map(lambda element: string in element, list))`, but that would also just be a less readable way of writing the same thing.

Comment: another way would be to join the list: `string in '|'.join(list)` try [timeit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) to find out which is the fastest way if you are interested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really hate for String concat is one way you can implement. Other ones can be list comprehension but that's just one liner version of for loop.

Also to be noted the answer below will take O(N) time so it's not really faster. Just a different way to implement.

```
arr = ["tree", "gate", "buy", "train", "test"]
ans = False
ele= "rain"
if ele in "~".join(arr): ans=True
ans
```

Comment: I just wanted an easy way to write it and it seems this is the easiest. Thank you!

Comment: Can I ask an additional thing: if i have arr = ["+", "-", "*", "/"] string="one/two" as input and I want to obtain ["one", "/", "two"] in output. More clearly, if an element of arr appears in the string, in this case how can I found it?

Comment: look into `string.split` It does what you want.